# Centering inline element inside div without flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to acomplish something that should be easy: centering an `a` tag inside a `div`. I know this is a classic, that there are similar questions out there, and also that can be done with flexbox, but I am trying to avoid the latter.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  border: 4px dashed white;
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<a>
  Link
</a>
</div>
```

Any help will be welcome!

EDIT: I would like the `a` tag to be flexible and fill the `wrapper`, without knowing the height of the wrapper.

Comment: Does vijay's answer below work for you?

Comment: No, because it uses a fixed line-height, and I would like it to be flexible (without flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

Add line-height in wrapper div

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height:200px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  border: 4px dashed white;
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<a>
  Link
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew that solution, and it works. I should say that I want the `a` tag to be flexible and fill the outer wrapper. I will update the question…